# Does an increase in pressure necessarily lead to an increase in temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

Ideal gas law says that $pV = nRT$. So with compression, one way to add pressure which makes the volume smaller, can you actually increase the temperature?

It does not make sense to me that you can increase temperature, that is, add to the kinetic energy of the molecules, simply by increasing pressure, pressure meaning the force exerted on the gas from its surroundings. Can someone please explain this contradiction?

Comment: pressure does not mean the force exerted on the gas by the surroundings, it means the force exerted **by** the gas on the walls of the container divided by the area of the wall.

Comment: Ok fair enough feed back about wording

Comment: Karl, are you saying that, in the adiabatic compression of an ideal gas in a closed system (e.g., an insulated cylinder with a piston), there is no change in the gas internal energy or temperature?

Comment: Really.  Then please comment on the following for the case of an adiabatic reversible volume change:  $dU=nC_vdT=-PdV=-\frac{nRT}{V}dV$.  So, $d\ln T=-\frac{R}{C_v}d\ln V$.  So, when the volume decreases, the temperature increases.

Comment: I mixed up free expansion and reversible compression/expansion.

Comment: Sorry I'm a muggle. Not sure how to work this Q and As. But in answer to the question I thought that compressed gases got colder if anything. Could be wrong of course. Thought that you slow the movements of particles when you compress things and if they are moving slower they are colder. There may come a point when they can't be compressed any further and then they'd probably explode.

Answer (score 8):

I think what you are asking is "why can the temperature of the gas increase when you compress it, even if the cylinder is adiabatic so that no heat can enter the gas?"  When you move the piston to compress the gas, you are doing work on the gas at the interface with the piston.  The piston is moving toward the gas, and the molecules of gas that collide with the piston leave with a greater average velocity than when they arrived.  So their average kinetic energy is increasing.  If expansion were occurring, such that the piston were moving away from the gas, the colliding molecules would leave with lower average kinetic energy.

Comment: Who said anything about compression rate?  In the end, it is only the total amount of work that determines the change in temperature, but that's just equal to the integral of the force per unit area at the piston face times the rate of change of volume (compression rate) dt.  You know, for an adiabatic process, $\Delta U = -\int{P_{ext}dV}$, where, for an ideal gas U = U(T).

Comment: I stand by what I said.

Comment: Are you talking about an ideal gas or air?  For air at least part of the reason is that the molecules attract each other and it is not ideal.  Would an ideal gas increase in temperature?  (Either way PV=nRT, does not say wither T changes.)  A good question not answered here or anywhere else I could find.

Comment: @Tuntable I am talking about both real gases and ideal gases.  Of course, an ideal gas would also increase in temperature.  PV-nRT is not the only characteristic of an ideal gas that matters.  The first law of thermodynamics also comes into play here, and, for an ideal gas, the internal energy is a function of temperature.  Did you read my comments to the OP's post?

Comment: It is not at all clear that an ideal gas would increase in temperature, at least not significantly.  Sure, increasing the pressure increases enthalpy, but enthalpy is T+PV.  If you are sure that it increase temperature of an ideal gas, then by how much?  Do you have a formula or a reference?

Comment: @Tuntable First of all, enthalpy is not T+PV.  Secondly, the ideal gas law tells us that, for an adiabatic reversible process of any gas, $dU=-pdV$.  For the case of an ideal gas, this reduces to $$nC_vdT=-\frac{nRT}{V}dV$$So, if dV is negative, dT is positive.  This is every thermodynamics textbook.  So stop wasting my time.

Comment: The ideal gas law, PV=nRT, only tells us how to calculate the pressure given the temperature and volume.  Compressing the gas certainly increases U, which includes both temperature and pressure, not sure why you hold pressure constant.  I have never seen this explained properly, just vagueness, leaps and then differential equations.

Comment: Who said the pressure is constant?  And, for an ideal gas, U depends only on temperature, not pressure.

Comment: It’s beginning to dawn on me that you are uncomfortable because you can’t see why U would not depend on p for the case of an ideal gas.  Is that your issue?

Comment: Sorry, got my U and H mixed up.  Not sure why enthalpy is not essentially T+PV, given a non-reacting ideal gas T is essentially U + constant.  When you say dU = -pdV then you are holding p constant, changing the volume, so obviously the temperature must change.  But it says nothing about what happens to the temperature if you just compress the gas increasing its pressure, adiabaticly.  I think what I am after is a good link if you know one, rather than an explanation.

Comment: Found it at last!!  Joule-Thompson effect.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect

As I suspected, for Helium at normal temperatures, there is no increase in temperature at all.  The rise when one compresses air has nothing to do with PV=nRT, but only to do with the non-ideal nature of air.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 4):

If you had a way to increase pressure with no volume change, then yes, temperature would increase by the ideal gas law.  In reality, most compression take place by reducing volume or increasing N, so the temperature effect is hard to see directly because other things are changing too.

The pressure in PV=nRT is the force exerted by the gas on the walls of the container.  As the temperature increases, the particles move faster, and therefore have greater speeds, so greater momentum and therefore greater force when they collide with the walls, so the pressure increases.

Comment: I understand what youre saying and I agree. Yes the ideal gas law says it happens in theory but does it actually happen in reality without changing the volume or the number of atoms?

Comment: How can you compress a gas without changing its volume?  Compressing means decreasing its volume.

Comment: I was commenting on the idea of changing pressure without volume, not compression.

Comment: At constant volume, you need to add heat to raise the temperature so that the pressure can increase.  The temperature rise is the cause and the pressure rise is the effect, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Ok, yes thats the idea I was getting at in the previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: @chestermiller  I didn't mean one could compress s system without changing volume, or that one could do an experiment in a lab today to raise temperature by changing pressure (thats why I said "if" and "in reality") but what I was getting at is that there is a direct correlation between pressure and temperature that would go both ways if the experiment could be done with everything else fixed.  In real experiment, yes, it usually is temperature that is raised, but thats not what the question was asking.

Comment: @JiffFulcher you can increase the pressure by putting more gas into the containers. The container stays the same size and has the same volume

Comment: The original question was whether just decreasing the volume would increase the temperature for an IDEAL gas.  Obviously the pressure increases, per PV = nRT.  But what about the temperature?  For air, the temperature increases, but air is not ideal.  Please do not provide non-answers.

Answer (score 0):

We all know, Solids have defenite size and obviously have defenite volume. Liquid has defenite volume but no shape. Gases have neither shape nor volume. Gas will occupy the available volume of the container. Molecules make use of the available free space for their movement.

Thus in gases, you can externally change the degree of freedom of its molecules. When you increase the container volume, you are increasing the degree of freedom of the gas molecules. And conversely also it is true.

Coming to the question, when you decrease the degree of freedom of molecules (by decreasing the container volume), due to the limitation in their mobility, the excess residual energy has to be given out (All system trend to minimize its energy state). Naturally the gas becomes hot in a big to exchange the excess energy to the surrounding.
(Most of the natural energy exchange is done by heat energy).